# Download data from JSON and store to CoreData and Display in the same time when data downloads in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, core-data

I am parsing data from JSON and Storing to CoreData in the same time i am displaying the the data to tableview but the problem i am having is data is displaying only after download completed but i dont want like this i want to download the data in background and display the data while downloading is processed also how can i do this

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    arrayData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arrayData count]; i++) {

        idNum = [arrayData objectAtIndex:i][@"id"];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Discount"];
        [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cID = %@",idNum]];
        [request setFetchLimit:1];
        NSUInteger count = [context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (count == NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR");
        }else if (count == 0) {
            NSLog(@"New Data Coming");

            name  = [arrayData objectAtIndex:i][@"name"];
            summary = [arrayData objectAtIndex:i][@"summary"];
            region = [arrayData objectAtIndex:i][@"region"];
            imageURL = [arrayData objectAtIndex:i][@"images"][@"logo"];

            id  benefits1 = [arrayData objectAtIndex:i][@"benefits"];
            benefiteString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[benefits1 objectAtIndex:0][@"key"],[benefits1 objectAtIndex:0][@"value"]];
            NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
            dateUpdate = [arrayData objectAtIndex:i][@"updated_at"];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ"];
            NSDate *date =[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateUpdate];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"];
            NSLog(@"DAte : %@",date);
            Discount * d = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Discount" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            d.name = name;
            d.summary = summary;
            d.regions = region;
            d.cID = idNum;
            d.imageLogo = data;
            d.updated_at = date;
            d.benefits = benefiteString;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Getting error while saving data");
            }
            else{
                NSLog(@"Saved");
            }
        }

    }
    [sharedAppDelegate dismissGlobalHUD];
    [listTableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_myArray count];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customCellClass = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (customCellClass == nil)
    {
        customCellClass = [[CellCustom alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    customCellClass.nameLabel.text = [[_myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
    customCellClass.cityLabel.text =[[_myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]regions];
    customCellClass.detailLabel.text = [[_myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]summary];

    NSData * d = [[_myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]imageLogo];
    customCellClass.mainImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:d];

    customCellClass.benefitsLabel.text = [[_myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]benefits];
    [sharedAppDelegate dismissGlobalHUD];
    return customCellClass;
}

-(void)dataDidSave
{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Discount" inManagedObjectContext:context]; [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    self.myArray = result;
    [listTableView reloadData];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [sharedAppDelegate showGlobalProgressHUDWithTitle:@"Loading..."];
    [self dataDidSave];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In connectionDidFinishLoading: try something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^ {
   // Process your data and then incrementally call 
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {
           [listTableView reloadData];
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes after download completes it is adding to array and displaying but is there a way that download has to be happened in background and display the download in asynchronosly

Comment: Your connectionDidFinishLoading: is likely being executed by the main thread. You can check this by logging [NSThread isMainThread]. If so, I would throw the whole handler for connectionDidFinishLoading: onto a background queue and enqueue your UI updates from that queue.

Comment: am not getting you you have any sample for this solution

Comment: See the sample code I pasted. UI updates can only occur on the main thread (Thread 1). In XCode, you can place a breakpoint on connectionDidFinishLoading and you will be able to see which thread is running. Chances are you are in fact running on Thread 1, which means that the UITableView refresh won't occur until after all processing is complete on that thread. Solution is to move the heavy duty data processing to a background thread and incrementally dispatch the main thread (thread 1) as needed to refresh the table.

Comment: just copy and put this in didfinishloading ?